# spring security: allow actuator endpoints

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here my code:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(
            authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(
                    EndpointRequest.to(InfoEndpoint.class, HealthEndpoint.class, EnvironmentEndpoint.class))
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin(cr -> cr.disable());
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

I think above code allows `_/actuator/env` request without any authentication.

Nevertheless:

```
❯ http localhost:9090/actuator/env
HTTP/1.1 403
...
```

Spring security debug logs:

```
2023-11-16T16:09:18.834+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@3e8799f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3b353651, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@1290ed28, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@a6c54c3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4373f66f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@5c887052, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3610f277, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@270d43a7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2b916808, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@33f17289]] (1/1)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.835+01:00 DEBUG 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /actuator/env
2023-11-16T16:09:18.835+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.836+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.836+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.836+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.836+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.836+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-11-16T16:09:18.837+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (6/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.837+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2023-11-16T16:09:18.837+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.837+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.837+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.838+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (10/10)
2023-11-16T16:09:18.838+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@14d8e31b]
2023-11-16T16:09:18.838+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@14d8e31b] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@6f5c58c
2023-11-16T16:09:18.839+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2023-11-16T16:09:18.839+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-16T16:09:18.839+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-11-16T16:09:18.839+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-11-16T16:09:18.840+01:00 TRACE 241896 --- [nio-9090-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the documented way: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.security

Comment: I had such a problem only by POST methods for actuator, and I must disable csrf.